# Sufficient statistic for normal distribution (not iid)

Tags: statistics, sufficient-statistics

I am a bit confused with this exercise, since I never worked with samples of this type. I would appreciate if you can help me. The exercise is as follows:

> Let **$\{Xi\} \sim N(iθ, 1)$ for $i = 1, .... , n$** be an independent, but not identically distributed sample. Check that **$T = \sum_iX_i$**  it is a sufficient statistic for **$θ$**.

What I need is to verify that the $T$ statistic is sufficient for the $\theta$ parameter. I know how to do it with the Fisher and Neymann factorization theorem, but always with a identically distributed sample of random variables. In this case, the sample is not identically distributed. Therefore, I don't know how to verify it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What I need is to verify that the T statistic is sufficient for the theta parameter. I know how to do it with the Fisher and Neymann factorization theorem, but always with a identically distributed sample of random variables. In this case, the sample is not identically distributed. Therefore, I don't know how to verify it. That's the problem. Thanks!

Comment: This time , I agree Community's comment.

Comment: Essentially you want to use the factorisation theorem by finding the density or likelihood associated with a set of observations and then tidy it up with the aim of factorising.  Without doing the calculations, I would guess  $\sum_i X_i$ may not be sufficient but $\sum_i iX_i$ might be, though this may be completely wrong

Comment: Independence is enough to find the joint density of $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$; you don't need the sample to be identically distributed.

Comment: The explanation of the problem is clearer than water. The question is very simple. I need to verify that a statistic is sufficient for a parameter. It does not have much mystery. I don't know what else I can explain to you people. If they don't know the subject, no problem. But do not tell me I lack details in the explanation, when it is very clear. Thank you for your answers. I consider the issue resolved.

Answer (score 1):

We have that the probability density function of $X_i$ is
$$f_{X_i}(x_i) = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left[ -\dfrac{1}{2}\left(x_i-i\theta \right)^2\right]\text{.}$$
By independence, the joint density is given by
$$f_{X_1, \dots, X_n}(x_1, \dots, x_n) = \prod_{i=1}^{n}f_{X_i}(x_i) = \dfrac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}}\exp\left[-\dfrac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i - i\theta)^2 \right]\text{.}$$
Now we expand the sum:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i - i\theta)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2 - 2\theta\sum_{i=1}^{n}ix_i + \theta\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^2\text{.}$$
Recalling the sum
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^2 = \dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$$
we obtain
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i - i\theta)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2+\theta\left[\dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}- 2\sum_{i=1}^{n}ix_i\right]\text{.}$$
The joint density may thus be written as
$$\underbrace{\dfrac{1}{(2\pi)^{n/2}}\exp\left[-\dfrac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2\right]}_{h(\mathbf{x})}\underbrace{\exp\left\{ \theta\left[\dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}- 2\sum_{i=1}^{n}ix_i\right]\right\}}_{\varphi(\sum_{i=1}^{n}ix_i, \theta)}\text{.}$$
By the factorization criterion, $\sum_{i=1}^{n}iX_i$ is sufficient for $\theta$.

Unless there's something I'm missing here, I don't think $\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i$ is sufficient for $\theta$.