# Show that T is a sufficient statistic (not iid sample)

Tags: statistical-inference

I am a bit confused with this exercise, since I never worked with samples of this type. I would appreciate if you can help me. The exercise is as follows:

Let {Xi} ~ N(iθ, 1) for i = 1, .... , n be an independent, but not identically distributed sample. Check that T = ΣiXi it is a sufficient statistic for θ.

Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do not [repost](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4244217/321264) please.